# Pip3 installing of Tensorflow issue

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to install python and tensorflow to learn as part of a class I am taking, and am having some issues installing tensorflow. I keep getting the same set of errors:

```
C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in 'C:\\'
```

or

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling python while adding it to my path, and that solved me not being stuck with syntax errors (most of the time), but  I haven't been able to make any progress. Any advice on moving forward would be appreciated.

To be clear, I am typing the following command into my command prompt:

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

As per [the instructions on the TensorFlow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows) - I've been finding the "C:\>" raises a syntax error however.

Comment: You need to update your pip: pip install --upgrade pip

Comment: According to my computer, my requirements for pip are up to date.

Answer (score 0):

your pip3 is broken, because I can clearly see tensorflow distribution on PyPi for python 3.6 https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tensorflow/1.5.0. Also, I just created a new virtual env for python 3.6 and I am able to `pip install` it.

Also you can download manually the "tensorflow-1.5.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl",assuming you have windows, and `pip install tensorflow-1.5.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`

Comment: I get the following error, while trying to manually install:

    tensorflow-1.5.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.